# Set margin for every CSS page-break start

Tags: html, css

Pardon me for the title, I couldn't find a more accurate description for it.

I'm breaking long rows in a table into several pages.
Everything is ok with `page-break-after` for `<tr>`.
My only problem is, it starts at the very beginning and ends at the very bottom of a page, making my header & footer covered by the table data.

I tried putting margin and padding everywhere but none seems to work.

Below is my CSS:

```css
@media print {
    
    html, body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;  
        background:#fff;
    }
    .page-layout {
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;           
    }
    
    table.report { page-break-after:auto }
    table.report tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    table.report td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    table.report thead { display:table-header-group; margin-top:50px; }
    table.report tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
    
    .header {
        display:block; 
        position:fixed; 
        top: 0px;   
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:14px;
        text-align:right;
        right:0px;
    }
    .footer {
        z-index: 1;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        text-align: left;
        left: 0;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }       
}
```

Below is my HTML:

```html
<div class="header">MY HEADER</div>

<div class="page-layout">
    <div style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; text-align:center; margin-bottom:20px">REPORT TITLE</div>

    <table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse" class="report">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="10%">Col1</th>
                <th width="60%">Col2</th>
                <th width="10%">Col3</th>
                <th width="20%">Col4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php for ($x=1; $x<100; $x++) {//loop ?>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><?=$x?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="center"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } //endloop ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="footer">MY FOOTER</div>
```

Here is what it looks like when printing:
[image]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lg82o6bh/ Fiddle with filled table.

Answer (score 18):

After intensive research on the net, I found that there is no proper way to do it.

There is a discussion about [`@page rule`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm) that is likely what I intended to achieve. Unfortunately it didn't work. I learned that this feature has not been implemented in most browsers yet. I don't know which browsers support it.

Finally, I came across a trick. The `thead` and `tfoot` elements are designed to repeat on print. So I put a blank row in the `thead` at the top, leaving an empty space every time it was repeated, just enough for the header to show up. And also an empty row below `tfoot` for the footer area.

Unfortunately, `tfoot` didn't repeat itself in Chrome. IE and Firefox are ok.

Comment: i know this is late, but i was able to get this working by adding a padding-top to my page-break element.

Comment: Seem Safari doesn't repeat tfoot and thead too.

Comment: I wonder if you could share your final solution for this. I am searching the internet to find a good solution, but unfortunately, most of them don't work on modern browsers.

Answer (score 11):

If you have this kind of problems when after and before table start needs some extra space for other page footer, like this:

[image]

you can fix it this way:

```
<style>
   @media print {
   .table-breaked {
      page-break-before: auto;
   }
   .no-border{
      border: none !important;
   }
   .footer-repeat {
      display: table-footer-group;
     }
   }
</style>


<div class="table-breaked">
 <table class="pt-20">
      <thead>
         <tr class="no-border">
            <td class="no-border">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
          <!-- add extra space for printing -->
         <tr class="no-border">
            <td class="no-border">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <!-- add extra space for printing -->
         <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Value 1<br/>№ Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Value 2</th>
            <th class="text-center">Value 3</th>
            <th class="text-center">Value 4</th>
            <th class="text-center">Value 5</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <!-- more trs here -->
         <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot class="footer-repeat">
         <!-- add repeated tfoot for extra space -->
         <tr class="no-border">
            <td class="no-border">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="no-border">
            <td class="no-border">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="no-border">
            <td class="no-border">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="no-border">
            <td class="no-border">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="no-border">
            <td class="no-border">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
      </tfoot>
   </table>
</div>
```

Here is a result:

[image]

Comment: But how to not-show the top 2 extra rows on the first page. That now leaves a large empty space

Comment: Ha fixing print issues the same way we fix email html, love it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
@page{
  size: A4;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This just adjusts margins. Fixed positioned footer still overlaps with content

Comment: This will help only in case your PDF don't have custom background colors. Also you can just enable margins in library you're using for generating PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Adding page-break-inside:avoid to the cells worked for me:

```
table td, table th {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had Same problem and fix it by this trick
add this line in your view :

```
<tr @if($key+1 ==3) class="break_page"  @endif>
```

and in your css :

```
/** Fix for Chrome issue #273306 **/
@media print {enter code here
    body.A3.landscape { width: 420mm }
    body.A3, body.A4.landscape { width: 297mm }
    body.A4, body.A5.landscape { width: 210mm }
    body.A5                    { width: 148mm }

    .break_page {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

and then add to your layout html :

```
@page { size: A4;
            margin-top: 50px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve this for my use case by setting `position: relative; top: 100px;` on the top-most element.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
@media print {

    html, body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;  
        background:#fff;
    }
    .page-layout {
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;           
    }       
    table.report { page-break-after:auto }
    table.report tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    table.report td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    table.report thead { display:table-header-group; margin-top:50px; }
    table.report tfoot { display:table-footer-group }

    .header {
        display:block; 
        position:fixed; 
        top: 0px;   
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:14px;
        text-align:right;
        right:0px;
    }
    .footer {
        z-index: 1;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        text-align: left;
        left: 0;
        width:100%;
        display:block;
    }       
}
```

```html
<div class="header">MY HEADER</div> 
<div class="page-layout">
<div style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; text-align:center; margin-bottom:20px">REPORT TITLE</div>

<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse" class="report">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="10%">Col1</th>
<th width="60%">Col2</th>
<th width="10%">Col3</th>
<th width="20%">Col4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center">1</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">2</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">3</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">4</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">5</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">6</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">7</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">8</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">9</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">10</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">11</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">12</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">13</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">14</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">15</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">16</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">17</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">18</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">19</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">20</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">21</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">22</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">23</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">24</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">25</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">26</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">27</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">28</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">29</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">30</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">31</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">32</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">33</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">34</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">35</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">36</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">37</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">38</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">39</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">40</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">41</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">42</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">43</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">44</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">45</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">46</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">47</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">48</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">49</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">50</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">51</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">52</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">53</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">54</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">55</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">56</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">57</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">58</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">59</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">60</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">61</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">62</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">63</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">64</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">65</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">66</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">67</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">68</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">69</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">70</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">71</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">72</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">73</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">74</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">75</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">76</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">77</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">78</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">79</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">80</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">81</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">82</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">83</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">84</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">85</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">86</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">87</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">88</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">89</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">90</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">91</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">92</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">93</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">94</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">95</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">96</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">97</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">98</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">99</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>  
<div class="footer">MY FOOTER</div>
```

Comment: not work. 
the header & footer are fine on screen, but overlapped on paper.

Comment: H works fine till the moment you need calculate to values inside for every page. The problem is headers are rendered only one time so you have only first page calculation done but no for other which are fully copied :(