# Handlebars set margin top in #each when there are entries on new a page

Tags: html, handlebars.js

When I use Handlebar to go through a large list with #each, it automatically makes a new page if it doesn't fit for all the entries on one page. On the new page it has no space to the margin and looks unattractive. How can I set the distance from the margin?

[image]

This is my code:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>{{Person.Known}}</th>
  <th>{{Person.Unknown}}</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

{{#each OriginalDocuments.Documents }}
  <tr>
    <td>{{this.Name}} - {{@index}}</td>
    <td>
      {{#if this.Known}}
        <div>
          <img src="person_checkmark_Known.svg"/>
        </div>
      {{/if}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{#if this.Unknown}}
        <div>
          <img src="person_checkmark_Unknown.svg"/>
        </div>
      {{/if}}
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}

</tbody>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Margins on the page, margins on the table, padding, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set margin for every CSS page-break start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991960/set-margin-for-every-css-page-break-start)

Comment: Nope, I have forgotten to say that in the end it generates a pdf from the html... Is there a posibility to set page border on every page?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add this to the `style` section of your `handlebars` template:

```
@page {
  margin: 10px 0; 
}
```

The above will add 10px of margin to the top and bottom of each page that ends up being generated. You can style as you see fit by using `@page`, and that will be applied to each page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this but the problem was in IronPdf... I had to define  ironPdf.PrintOptions.MarginTop = 13.4;

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying the problem is.  I have a project where I also needed to add margin for each page being printed for a PDF and this worked perfectly. Can you clarify why what you state above was an insurmountable problem? It may help if you show the code for the handlebars document.